# Bootstrap clickable menu on hover

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have customized using jquery the bootstrap navigation whereby instead of clicking to enable the dropdown menu you can simply hover. However, I am trying to get it so the first menu is clickable as currently it is not. For example currently BLOG isn't clickable but I would like it to be. The other categories are clickable.

[image]

Does anyone have any experience in this on bootstrap? It is being built on wordpress. The jquery I used to allow the menu to show on hover is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var mq = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)');
  if (mq.matches) {
    jQuery('ul.navbar-nav li').addClass('hovernav');
  } else {
    jQuery('ul.navbar-nav li').removeClass('hovernav');
  };
    /*
    The addClass/removeClass also needs to be triggered
  on page resize <=> 768px
    */
  if (matchMedia) {
    var mq = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)');
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
  }
    function WidthChange(mq) {
    if (mq.matches) {
      jQuery('ul.navbar-nav li').addClass('hovernav');
    } else {
      jQuery('ul.navbar-nav li').removeClass('hovernav');
    }
  };


});
```

The css is:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav .caret {
        display:none;
    }

    .navbar-nav .open ul {
        display:none;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
        color:#555;
        background:none;
    }

    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
        color:#969696;
        background:none;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .hovernav > a {
        color:#555;
    }

    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .hovernav > a {
        color:#969696;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .hovernav:hover > a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .hovernav:hover > a:hover,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .hovernav:hover > a:focus {
        color:#333;
        background:transparent;
    }

    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .hovernav:hover > a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .hovernav:hover > a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .hovernav:hover > a:focus {
        color:#F7F7F7;
        background:transparent;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover {
        background:#e7e7e7;
    }

    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li:hover {
        background:#080808;
    }

    .navbar-nav .hovernav:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problems using matchMedia/media queries to accomplish what you're doing:

*Media queries for many touch devices are the same as desktop.*

Hover does not exist on touch. IOS takes a hover and one click triggers the dropdown 2 clicks get to the link, BUUUT android doesn't work this way. So on touch devices those drop menus won't be accessible. How to do this correctly:

1. Detect touch and no-touch on Android, IOS, and Windows 8 phones.
2. Remove the Attribute data-toggle on the .dropdown a link -- removing
   this allows the click to work on that toggle.
3. Wrap the removing attribute in an if statement if no-touch
4. Wrap the hover script in a no-touch if statement
5. Have a fallback for touch devices so they can get to the first menu
   item

---

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/ejAXoda/1/

Edit: http://jsbin.com/ejAXoda/1/edit

---

**CSS**

```
.touch .mobile-link {display:block;}
.no-touch .mobile-link {display:none}
```

**Script(s)**

```
/* ----- Detect touch or no-touch */
/*  Detects touch support and adds appropriate classes to html and returns a JS object
 *  Copyright (c) 2013 Izilla Partners Pty Ltd
 *  http://www.izilla.com.au
 *  Licensed under the MIT license
 *  https://coderwall.com/p/egbgdw
 */
var supports = (function () {
    var a = document.documentElement,
        b = "ontouchstart" in window || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints;
    if (b) {
        a.className += " touch";
        return {
            touch: true
        }
    } else {
        a.className += " no-touch";
        return {
            touch: false
        }
    }
})();

// -------- DO the stuff only on no-touch devices only

if ($("html").hasClass("no-touch")) {


// ------- REMOVE THE DATA TOGGLE ONLY ON "no-touch" devices and get the link to work
  $('.dropdown > a').removeAttr("data-toggle");  


// Hover dropdown for Bootstrap 3.x wrapped in this no-touch var
    /*
     * Project: Bootstrap Hover Dropdown
     * Author: Cameron Spear
     * Contributors: Mattia Larentis
     *
     * Dependencies: Bootstrap's Dropdown plugin, jQuery
     *
     * A simple plugin to enable Bootstrap dropdowns to active on hover and provide a nice user experience.
     *
     * License: MIT
     *
     * http://cameronspear.com/blog/bootstrap-dropdown-on-hover-plugin/
     */
    (function (e, t, n) {
        if ("ontouchstart" in document) return;
        var r = e();
        e.fn.dropdownHover = function (n) {
            r = r.add(this.parent());
            return this.each(function () {
                var i = e(this),
                    s = i.parent(),
                    o = {
                        delay: 500,
                        instantlyCloseOthers: !0
                    }, u = {
                        delay: e(this).data("delay"),
                        instantlyCloseOthers: e(this).data("close-others")
                    }, a = e.extend(!0, {}, o, n, u),
                    f;
                s.hover(function (n) {
                    if (!s.hasClass("open") && !i.is(n.target)) return !0;
                    a.instantlyCloseOthers === !0 && r.removeClass("open");
                    t.clearTimeout(f);
                    s.addClass("open");
                    s.trigger(e.Event("show.bs.dropdown"))
                }, function () {
                    f = t.setTimeout(function () {
                        s.removeClass("open");
                        s.trigger("hide.bs.dropdown")
                    }, a.delay)
                });
                i.hover(function () {
                    a.instantlyCloseOthers === !0 && r.removeClass("open");
                    t.clearTimeout(f);
                    s.addClass("open");
                    s.trigger(e.Event("show.bs.dropdown"))
                });
                s.find(".dropdown-submenu").each(function () {
                    var n = e(this),
                        r;
                    n.hover(function () {
                        t.clearTimeout(r);
                        n.children(".dropdown-menu").show();
                        n.siblings().children(".dropdown-menu").hide()
                    }, function () {
                        var e = n.children(".dropdown-menu");
                        r = t.setTimeout(function () {
                            e.hide()
                        }, a.delay)
                    })
                })
            })
        };
        e(document).ready(function () {
            e('[data-hover="dropdown"]').dropdownHover()
        })
    })(jQuery, this);

 } //END IF no-touch for hover script & removeAttr for the links to work
```

**SAMPLE HTML with fallback for the link:**

```
 <!-- Static navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="http://getbootstrap.com" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000" data-close-others="false">Blog <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">


            <!-- add for touch they won't be able to get to the link -->
            <li class="mobile-link"><a href="blog.html">Latest News</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
```

I tested this on Android. Test this on IOS, Windows 8, and other devices before awarding/accepting. Should work smoothly.

Comment: I don't see how it works on mobile, the parent link does not lead to its href. It is just expand and collapse sub levels. (Tested on android)

Comment: Read more carefully. There is no hover on touch devices so that click either opens the link OR it toggles the dropdown it doesn't do both. In this set up it toggles the dropdown on touch devices and on no-touch devices it hovers so that you can either click the parent or use the dropdown.

Comment: But what the point to make it work on desktop only?
In my opinion the menu should have the same functionality in all devices. So if you can't keep it work everywhere it is better not to build it using bootstrap...

Comment: Nothing to do with Bootstrap. Click menus work on both desktop and touch, hover is not a function that works on touch devices, so you have to make a workaround. Do so more learning.

Comment: I wasn't talking about hover and click, I was talking about what the point doing parent item work (navigational) on desktop and not navigational on mobile. nothing to do about more learning. The concept is wrong from the beginning. The title of this topic is "Bootstrap clickable menu on hover". You have provided a solution for desktop but not for mobile.

Comment: And there is no such thing: the tap either opens the children menu or it goes to a link -- not both.

Comment: Well, actually you can do both with some small js codding. First click could open the sub menu and the second click on the same item could lead to it's url. Or you can add a small icon near menu item title let's say "small arrow" if you click it, the menu will expend, if you click the title text it will navigate to it.
In such way you keep the same UX in both desktop and mobile.

Comment: It's not the same UX since hover doesn't exist. Two taps is not normal so people wouldn't know what's going on with the menu, that's why google, bootstrap and other click menus are NOT making it 2 taps to go to page on the parent, one tap to see the sub menus, or using the arrow/icon to be the drop menu and the link separate. That's a mystery meat menu you're describing and not a good plan.

Comment: Not a such good plan making different functionality for different platforms. Actually that's what called good UI when all functionality is the same on all platforms in UI perspective, it is the basics of UX. Do some learning...
You can find lots of such plugins online, it is not only my opinion... See this as an example one of hundrets... http://jasonweaver.name/lab/flexiblenavigation

Comment: And here is example of double tap, which is in "your opinion not normal and mystery": http://webdesigncone.com

Comment: It's not an opinion... google, bootstrap, superclick, the top click menus don't work that way and people don't know that they can tap 2x and they probably won't. If a person wants consistent UX, then it should only be click. I provided a solution for Bootstrap's click menu, the OP and anyone else is able to extend it or do something different. End of conversation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('mouseover', '.dropdown-toggle', function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).trigger('click')
})
```

or instead of ".dropdown-toggle" you could use the id of the element that triggers the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a

```
$("#blog").click(function(){
    window.location.href="blog.html";
});
```

and adding a `<div id="blog"></div>`?